# scan to wallet process

Tags: wallet

I just got interested in Bitcoin, set up  a wallet , received a coin w/ a code
and mnemonic but have no idea  how to scan it and deposit it to my wallet.
Is there a 'how to' link that explains this process?   Thanks, RS

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "code and mnemonic".  Is it something physical that you received?  What do you mean by "set up a wallet"?  Please start at the beginning and describe in detail what you have done so far, what you're trying to do and what you're seeing.

Comment: sounds like op got a paper wallet (qr code and maybe a bip 0038 passphrase?) we would need to know what wallet you are importing this into and if it is indeed password protected or not?